# Reading in 54 GB dataset with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Currently trying to get a sample of a very large dataset ~54 gb. However since I know that getting anything larger than 1 gb becomes very inefficient, I only want to read in the first 100k rows. This is what I have so far:

```
df_chunk = pd.read_csv(r'pol.csv', chunksize=1000000, engine='python')

    chunk_list = []  # append each chunk df here

    # Each chunk is in df format
    for chunk in df_chunk:
        # Once the data filtering is done, append the chunk to list
        chunk_list.append(chunk)

    # concat the list into dataframe
    df_concat = pd.concat(chunk_list)
```

However running this gives me this error:

```
 File "path", line 3121, in _get_lines new_rows.append(next(self.data)) _csv.Error: ',' expected after '"'
```

Changing the engine to C throws a parsing error, and then setting `low_memory = False` doesn't work with the python engine. Also setting setting `error_bad_lines= True` skips way to many rows from the dataset.

I just need a small chunk of the dataset to work with but its extremely hard to even get just that.

Comment: the error is telling you that you have malformed data, you'll need to investigate whether it's comma delimited or not

Comment: I would try with pyspark dataframe instead, they are more scalable than pandas, depending on your machine, but generally they should be able to digest your input file better...

Comment: @EdChum Thats what I was guessing. I know the data is an absolute mess, so I wouldn't be surprised if its in mixed formats (tsv, csv) is there a way to ignore it?

Comment: you can try to sample a few lines with command line tools other python , which is much more efficient on large text files

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be some formatting issues in your big CSV. I suggest you first make a smaller file with just a fraction of the data and inspect that manually for the formatting issues: They need to be fixed in order to be parsed successfully. To extract some portion, do

```py
with open('pol.csv') as f:
    with open('pol_part.csv','w') as g:
        for i in range(1000): # replace 1000 with 100000 when ready
            g.write(f.readline())
```

Comment: this sampling is  biased  when the large file is different formatted in large chunks ,   and can be improved by write one line after every reading 1000 or more lines.   longer time needed in this way.

Comment: @bigdataolddriver Yes this could be a problem. It is easy to retrieve different portions using just the standard arguments to `range()`.