# Formatting an unstructured csv in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

I'm having an issue reading in accurate information from archived 4chan comments. Since the structure of a thread of a 4chan thread doesn't (seem to) translate very well into a rectangular dataframe I'm having issues actually getting the appropriate comments from each thread into a single row in pandas.

To exacerbate the problem the dataset is 54GB in size and I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57772638/reading-in-54-gb-dataset-with-pandas) on how to just read the data into a pandas dataframe (in which the solution to that problem made me realize this issue) which makes diagnosing every problem tedious.

The code I use to read in portions of the data is as follows:

```
def Four_pleb_chunker():
    """
    :return: 4pleb data is over 54 GB so this chunks it into something manageable
    """
    with open('pol.csv') as f:
        with open('pol_part.csv', 'w') as g:
            for i in range(1000):   ready
                g.write(f.readline())

    name_cols = ['num', 'subnum', 'thread_num', 'op', 'timestamp', 'timestamp_expired', 'preview_orig', 'preview_w', 'preview_h',
            'media_filename', 'media_w', 'media_h', 'media_size', 'media_hash', 'media_orig', 'spoiler', 'deleted', 'capcode',
            'email', 'name', 'trip', 'title', 'comment', 'sticky', 'locked', 'poster_hash', 'poster_country', 'exif']

    cols = ['num','timestamp', 'email', 'name', 'title', 'comment', 'poster_country']

    df_chunk = pd.read_csv('pol_part.csv',
                           names=name_cols,
                           delimiter=None,
                           usecols=cols,
                           skip_blank_lines=True,
                           engine='python',
                           error_bad_lines=False)

    df_chunk = df_chunk.rename(columns={"comment": "Comments"})
    df_chunk = df_chunk.dropna(subset=['Comments'])
    df_chunk['Comments'] = df_chunk['Comments'].str.replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', ' ')

    df_chunk.to_csv('pol_part_df.csv')

    return df_chunk
```

This code works fine, however due to the structure of each thread a parser that I wrote sometimes returns nonsensical results. In csv form this is what the first few rows of the dataset look like (pardon the screen shot, its extremely difficult to actually write all those lines out using this UI.)

[image: screen shot of the data]

As it can be seen the comments per thread are split by '\' but then each comment doesn't take its own row. My goal is at least to get each comment into its own row so I can parse through it correctly. However the function I'm using to parse the data cuts off after 1000 iterations regardless if its a new line or not.

Fundamentally my questions are: How can I structure this data to actually read the comments accurately, and be able to read in a complete sample dataframe as opposed to a truncated one. As for solutions I've tried:

```
df_chunk = pd.read_csv('pol_part.csv',
                               names=name_cols,
                               delimiter='',
                               usecols=cols,
                               skip_blank_lines=True,
                               engine='python',
                               error_bad_lines=False)
```

If I get rid of/change the argument `delimiter` I get this error:

```
Skipping line 31473: ',' expected after '"'
```

Which makes sense because the data isn't separated by `,` so it skips every line that doesn't fit that condition, in this case the whole dataframe. inputing `\` into the argument gives me a syntax error. I'm kind of at a loss for what to do next, so if anyone has had any experience dealing with an issue like this you'd be a lifesaver. Let me know if there isn't something I've included in here and I'll update the post.

Update, here are some sample lines from the CSV for testing:

```
2   23594708    1385716767  \N  Anonymous   \N  Example: not identifying the fundamental scarcity of resources which underlies the entire global power structure, or the huge, documented suppression of any threats to that via National Security Orders. Or that EVERY left/right ideology would be horrible in comparison to ANY in which energy scarcity and the hierarchical power structures dependent upon it had been addressed.
3   23594754    1385716903  \N  Anonymous   \N  ">>23594701\
                                                 \
                                                  No, /pol/ is bait. That's the point."
4   23594773    1385716983  \N  Anonymous   \N  ">>23594754
                                                 \
                                                 Being a non-bait among baits is equal to being a bait among non-baits."
5   23594795    1385717052  \N  Anonymous   \N  Don't forget how heavily censored this board is! And nobody has any issues with that.
6   23594812    1385717101  \N  Anonymous   \N  ">>23594773\
                                                 \
                                                 Clever. The effect is similar. But there are minds on /pol/ who don't WANT to be bait, at least."
```

Comment: Personally I would write a different pure-python script using the built-in Python csv package to transform the entire dataset into the csv format that makes sense for you. This doesn't have to be fast because you only need to run it once. After that pandas read_csv shouldn't give any problems.

Comment: @rje I would like to do that, however, I'm not even sure how I would be able to read in each comment as a row, especially since the delimiters `'\'` for each comment are a new line in python syntax.

Comment: Can you include some lines from the csv so I can see what we are talking about?

Comment: @rje just added some

Comment: can you please let me know whether the solution worked? I'm curious ;)

Comment: @rje it just finished now with this error lol `TypeError: 'delimiter' is an invalid keyword argument for open()` I dont know why it took so long for the error to show

Comment: Sorry, apparently I copy/pasted the delimiter part into the wrong line. Fixed it.. again. Can you try one last time? I'm quite sure it should work now. Maybe just start with a smaller subset of your csv.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample script that converts your csv into separate lines for each comment:

```
import csv

# open file for output and create csv writer
f_out = open('out.csv', 'w')
w = csv.writer(f_out)

# open input file and create reader
with open('test.csv') as f:
    r = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
    for l in r:
        # skip empty lines
        if not l:
            continue
        # in this line I want to split the last part 
        # and loop over each resulting string
        for s in l[-1].split('\\\n'):
            # we copy all fields except the last one
            output = l[:-1]
            # add a single comment
            output.append(s)
            w.writerow(output)
```

Comment: Testing it now, right now I'm getting `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: well.. copy/pasting your csv from the website is bound to give problems. I added a delimiter since I figure your files are tab-delimited.. does it work now? If not, can you make a small part of the actual csv available for download?

Comment: Testing it now, so far I have run into any problems, it'll take a second.

Comment: also, now added some code to skip empty lines - which caused your problems.

Comment: I'm running it now with the line skips, I'tll take a hot minute though, so if it works I'll accept it as an answer!

Comment: last remark: change the second-to-last line into `output.append(s.strip())` and this will even strip away the extra whitespace around the comments ;)

Comment: So it finished last night, and did exactly what it was supposed to do however it put all information into one column as opposed to separating them `pandas.errors.ParserError: Too many columns specified: expected 28 and found 1` I think I know what went wrong I'll update the solution once I figure it out